# Parsing multiple dates from cell

Tags: arrays, list, parsing, google-sheets, formula

I've got a spreadsheet that, for goofy reasons, has two columns next to each other in each of which is a series of dates, separated by ctrl-rtn linefeeds. They amount to a list of start/stop periods. There are reasons it's done this way, and will probably continue to be (I am open to other suggestions).

Given this structure, I'd like to be able to pull out the periods and/or period lengths. That is, given:

```
1/1/2015          1/3/15
1/15/15          1/20/15  
2/3/15            2/7/15
```

(in only two adjacent cells) I'd like to be able to pull out at least:

```
2
5
4
```

and perhaps optionally break it up into six different cells (note that the lists will be variable lengths). This is much less important.

I am having a hard time figuring out how to even approach this. If I was in VBA I could regex it easy-peasy. I'm utterly new to Spreadsheet Scripts. Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Sorry my "cells" didn't format properly. Those dates are supposed to be 2 lists of 3 dates each vertically, though this is merely a readability issue, not substantive (well, it's also how it's stored in the spreadsheet).

Comment: Stupid question here, but have you considered exporting to Excel and using VBA on the problem?

Comment: have you already asked this in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I need it in Google Spreadsheet, it's shared. And thanks for the pointer to webapps.stackexchange, I didn't know about that. This has been answered below so I'll stop here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to split each cell (say A1) into three with:

```
=split(substitute(A1,char(10),","),",")
```

Repeat for the next (say A2), format as dates and in B3 and copied across to the right to suit:

```
=B2-B1
```